# Swap integers algorithm

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm

I am learning algorithms and try to to swap to integers in an array using Swift, I know that it is effective to use 'swap' function but I try to learn different approaches.
So I try different methods and I don't understand one thing - I have an array of 200 ints and when I use this method:

```
func selectionSort(var array: [Int]) {
 print("Selection Sort")
 for i in 0..<array.count {
    for j in i+1..<array.count {
        if array[j] < array[i] {
            let temp = array[j] //runs 7282 times
            array[j] = array[i] // runs 7282 times
            array[i] = temp     // runs 7282 times
        }
    }
 }
 print(array)
}
```

it runs for 7 seconds and swap code runs 7282 (or so) times, 
but when I use this:

```
func selectionSort(var array: [Int]) {
  print("Selection Sort")
  for i in 0..<array.count {
    for j in i+1..<array.count {
        if array[j] < array[i] {
            array.insert(array[j], atIndex: i)
            array.removeAtIndex(j+1)

        }
    }
  }
  print(array)
}
```

it runs only 198 times in 1.3 seconds?

I don't get why there is such different in number of runs? It appears only in selection sort.
There is no such differences in number of runs if I use ,for example, bubble sort.

Comment: Are you getting sorted arrays in both examples? It looks like the second method removes one of the values, and duplicates the other value, meaning your implementation might be incorrect. You'd expect less executions of the mentioned code because the predicate around it will not hold way more often if  you duplicate every value in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon further review I think I found the problem. The first sort will have to move the number many times to get it in its correct position. The second sort *moves multiple numbers at the same time* because the insert will *push other numbers forward* in the array. I tested it out with an array of 5 integers.

Here is the debugger before the first sort method begins:

[image]

Notice how 3 is far from its correct position, now after the first method sorts once, the array now looks like this

[image]

Now 3 is in the correct position, but 4 is now far from its correct position. It will have to repeat this and move 4 many times until it gets to its final position. The next swap looks like this

[image]

Now 14 was moved in front of 17 as it should, but its still far from its correct position. So it will have to be moved again!

---

Let's look at the second sort method.

Here's what it looks like before the sort

[image]

and after the first swap it looks like this

[image]

Now you can see that after just ONE swap, 3 AND 4 are in the correct positions. 3 was moved just one time, and because of this, it was moved in front of 4, which moved 4 to its correct position.

Now after one more swap...

[image]

Now you can see that it already is correctly sorted after 2 swaps using the second method, but it took the first method 4 swaps. The difference only grows when you have a larger array.

The second method moves multiple numbers by pushing numbers back by one index every time it inserts...

an example: 4,17,14,3,20

- 4 is currently at index 0
- 17 is currently at index 1
- 14 is currently at index 2

if i insert 3 in the front...

3,4,17,14,3,20

now remove the previous 3...

3,4,17,14,20

- 4 is now at index 1!
- 17 is now at index 2!
- 14 is now at index 3!

Comment: he is using an insert and remove each time, which keeps the array count the same

Comment: @Scriptable you're right. I was so wrong, I edited my answer. I think I found the problem

Comment: Good investigation, the code reads like its the exact same functionality but its not. Still doesnt quite make sense to me how its moving multiple numbers :(

Comment: It's moving multiple numbers because when you insert a number, it pushes every number back a slot, ill edit my answer to try to explain that part

Comment: yeah I understand that bit, but he's inserting at the index i which pushes them all along one, and then removing the index at j+1 therefore putting everything back in its place, but the two numbers swapped.

Comment: Not quite, when he removes the index at j+1, it doesn't put everything back in place, it only puts those numbers that came after j+1 back in place. If they were between the insertion point and j+1, then they were moved one place forward

Comment: ah, that makes sense, Thanks

Comment: @Luke Patterson, thank you very much! Now i understand the difference between them=)

Answer (score 2):

The methods are quite different.

The first one does a simple swap everytime `array[j] < array[i]`, as you expect.

The second one, when `array[j] < array[i]` is true, it moves `array[j]` to the `i`-th position and **shifts the rest of the array by one position**.

That being said, I had a bit of time on my hands so I decided to write your algorithms in Swift 3 (please note how you can avoid using `temp`):

```
func selectionSort(_ array: [Int]) {
  var array = array
  for i in 0..<array.count {
    for j in i+1..<array.count {
      if array[j] < array[i] {
        (array[j], array[i]) = (array[i], array[j])
      }
    }
  }
  print(array)
}

func selectionSort2(_ array: [Int]) {
  var array = array
  for i in 0..<array.count {
    for j in i+1..<array.count {
      if array[j] < array[i] {
        array.insert(array[j], at: i)
        array.remove(at: j+1)
      }
    }
  }
  print(array)
}
```

Cheers!